# Cocos2D-x tutorial. Target's position

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm having trouble to understand the math behind a piece of code of a tutorial of cocos2d. This piece of code is about getting the target's position of a bullet

```
void HelloWorld::ccTouchesEnded(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)
{
    // Choose one of the touches to work with
    CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch*)( touches->anyObject() );
    CCPoint location = touch->getLocationInView();
    location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);

    // Set up initial location of projectile
    CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    CCSprite *projectile = CCSprite::create("Projectile.png", CCRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20));
    projectile->setPosition( ccp(20, winSize.height/2) ); 

    // Determinie offset of location to projectile
    int offX = location.x - projectile->getPosition().x;
    int offY = location.y - projectile->getPosition().y;

    // Bail out if we are shooting down or backwards
    if (offX <= 0) return;

    // Ok to add now - we've double checked position
    this->addChild(projectile);

    // Determine where we wish to shoot the projectile to
    int realX = winSize.width + (projectile->getContentSize().width/2);
    float ratio = (float)offY / (float)offX;
    int realY = (realX * ratio) + projectile->getPosition().y;
    CCPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);

    // Determine the length of how far we're shooting

    // My comment: if in the next two lines we use (offX, offY) instead of (realX, realY)
    // bullet direction looks ok

    int offRealX = realX - projectile->getPosition().x;
    int offRealY = realY - projectile->getPosition().y;
    float length = sqrtf((offRealX * offRealX) + (offRealY * offRealY));
    float velocity = 480/1; // 480pixels/1sec
    float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;

    // Move projectile to actual endpoint
    projectile->runAction(  CCSequence::create( CCMoveTo::create(realMoveDuration, realDest),
                            CCCallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::spriteMoveFinished)), 
                            NULL) );

    // Add to projectiles array
    projectile->setTag(2);
    _projectiles->addObject(projectile);  
}
```

What I don't understand is the calculation of 'realY'. It looks like that it multiplies'ratio' as a tangent.

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

This seems tied up in whatever game design impact that code was written for.

Initial position of projectile :  20 pixels in, halfway up the screen. Perhaps this is where the "gun" is drawn?

Touch position : could be anywhere. I'm assuming that touch positions are reported in pixels.

Offset : draw a line between the initial position and the touch point.

If the user has touched to the left of the gun ('backwards') then we don't do anything.

realX : regardless of where the user touched, we want the bullet to travel the full width of the screen. So set the "x" coordinate of where we want to go to this value.

But now if we want to send the bullet along the angle or trajectory that was indicated by the user's touch, we need to scale up the Y coordinate of the destination. The ratio is a scale factor that tells us how, relative to the gun position, Y must change for a given X. We multiply our desired X destination by that slope, and add it to the bullet's starting point (halfway up the screen) and we have some 'destination' that is most likely offscreen but in the same direction as the touch coordinate.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Yes, the 20 pixels is because there is where the gun should be drawn. Anyway, to use realX and realY is really necessary? We already have the vector from bullet initial position to the target (offX, offY). If I use these values the bullet direction looks identical.

Comment: Without seeing all the code I don't know. I'd assume from this snippet that the bullet stops at the touch location without this extrapolation.

Comment: I have edited the code with the full body of the function, what do you think?

Comment: If you only replace the realX / realY where you indicated, you are only changing the calculation of the duration; the animation step still uses the destination object that does have the realX, realY coordinates, so it will still move off screen. By changing the duration you are effectively making it go faster.

Comment: Yes, that's what happens, my concern was only about the direction of the bullet, if the lines calculating realX and realY had really something to do with the direction of the bullet, because if I used offX and offY I'd have same direction. Thanks very much for your help :)